# SQL Server - How to sum duration based on few parameters from a table that will insert data for half an hour?

Tags: sql-server, grouping, self-join

Apologies me for the title as it might different than the actual issue

We are working for Contact Centers and our SQL Server tables will be capturing detailed information of Agent's going for Breaks, Login and Logout with Time, Duration and Reason.

When an agent going for Lunch @2PM and changing his state to Break @2:10Pm, then DB will update with Lunch Duration 600 Seconds. ie. After changing the state in Agent Screen, DB will insert the End Time and the duration occurred for that particular break reason.

If an event(Break) is continuing beyond 30 minutes, this table will put an entry for every 30 minutes until the agent changing his current state example below,

**Table raw data:**

```
Agent Name SkilltargetID Event  Date Time   ReasonText  Duration

Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 10:00    BioBreak    180 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 10:30    BioBreak    1800 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 11:00    BioBreak    1800 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 11:30    BioBreak    1800 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 11:42    BioBreak    720 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 12:01    Lunch   1140 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 12:30    Lunch   1740 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 12:32    Lunch   120 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 01:00    Bio Break   1680 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 01:29    Bio Break   1740 Seconds
```

We have a report that will show Date, Agent Name, Start Time, End Time, ReasonText(Break Reason) and Duration.

**Expected Output:**

```
Date    Agent Name SkillTargetID Event  Start Time  End Time    Reason  Duration

20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  9:57 AM 11:42 AM    Bio Break   6300
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  12:01 AM    12:32 AM    Lunch   3000
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  12:32 AM    1:29 PM Bio Break   3420
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Date    Agent Name SkillTargetID Event  Start Time  End Time    Reason  Duration

20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  9:57 AM 10:00 AM    Bio Break   180
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  10:00 AM    11:30 AM    Bio Break   5400
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  11:30 AM    11:42 AM    Bio Break   720
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  11:42 AM    12:01 AM    Lunch   1140
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  12:01 AM    12:30 AM    Lunch   1740
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  12:30 AM    12:32 AM    Lunch   120
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  12:32 AM    1:00 AM Bio Break   1680
20-08-2018  Sathiya 5000 3  1:00 AM 1:29 AM Bio Break   1740
```

We are trying to achieve using below query,

```
;WITH RCode ( ReasonCodeID, ReasonCode,ReasonText, Description )
AS (
  Select ReasonCodeID, ReasonCode,ReasonText, Description From Reason_Code 
                Union All
                Select 9999,0,'Not Ready-Default', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,-1,'Agent reinitialized (used if peripheral restarts)', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,-2,'PG reset the agent, normally due to a PG failure', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,-3,'An administrator modified the agent''s extension while the agent was logged in', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50002,'A CTI OS component failed, causing the agent to be logged out', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50003,'Agent was logged out because the Unified CM reported the device out of service', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50004,'Agent was logged out due to agent inactivity as configured in agent desk settings', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50005,'The Agent will be set to not ready with this code while talking on a call on the Non ACD line', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50020,'Agent was logged out when the agent''s skill group dynamically changed on the Administration & Data Server', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50040,'Mobile agent was logged out because the call failed', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50041,'Mobile agent state changed to Not Ready because the call fails when the mobile agent''s phone line rings busy.', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,50042,'Mobile agent was logged out because the phone line disconnected while using nailed connection mode', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
                Union All
                Select 9999,32767,'The agent''s state was changed to Not Ready because the agent did not answer a call and the call was redirected to a different agent or skill group', 'Not Ready-System Predefined'
),
CTE ( RowNum, SerialNum, DateTime, SkillTargetID, Event, Duration, ReasonCode) 
AS ( 
  SELECT
                RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITIOn BY SkillTargetID ORDER BY DateTime, SkillTargetID),
    SerialNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SkillTargetID, Event,Duration ORDER BY DateTime),
    DateTime, SkillTargetID, Event, Duration, ReasonCode
  FROM 
                                (Select DateTime,SkillTargetID, Event,
                                CASE WHEN (Duration=899 OR Duration=898 OR Duration=901 OR Duration=900) THEN 900 
                                                 WHEN (Duration=1799 OR Duration=1798 OR Duration=1801 OR Duration=1800) THEN 1800 
                                                 ELSE Duration end as 'Duration',
                                ReasonCode,RecoveryKey From TABLEA Where
                                SkillTargetID IN (5259)                   
                                And (Convert(varchar(10),DateTime,110)>= '07-10-2018' and convert(varchar(10),DateTime,110) <= '07-10-2018') ) A
)

--select * from CTE
,
CTE2 AS (
                                Select [Activity], Convert(varchar(10), [Activity], 101) AS [Date], 
                                                                Stuff(right(convert(varchar(30), [Activity], 109), 14), 9, 4, ' ') AS [End Time],
                                                                SkillTargetID, [Agent Name], Event,  [Duration], Z.ReasonCode [Reason Code], R.ReasonText [Reason], PrevDateTime,CTEDateTime, RowNum,SerialNum,PrevRow,CTENewRow From  


                                (Select CTE.RowNum RowNum, CTE.SerialNum SerialNum, CTE.DateTime CTEDateTime, CTE.SkillTargetID, 
                                                (Select B.LastName +', '+B.FirstName From Agent (nolock) Join Person B On Agent.PersonID = B.PersonID Where SkillTargetID=CTE.SkillTargetID) [Agent Name], prev.DateTime PrevDateTime, prev.RowNum PrevRow,((CTE.RowNum-CTE.SerialNum)+1) CTENewRow,
                                                Event = CASE WHEN CTE.Event = 1 THEN 'Sign-on' WHEN CTE.Event=2 THEN 'Sign-off'  WHEN CTE.Event=3 THEN 'Not-Ready' Else 'Unknown' END, 
                                CTE.Duration, CTE.ReasonCode,
                                                [Activity] = CASE               WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=1800 and CTE.SerialNum=1) THEN CTE.DateTime
                                                                                                                                WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=900 and CTE.SerialNum=1) THEN CTE.DateTime
                                                                                                                                WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=1800 and CTE.SerialNum<>1) THEN prev.DateTime 
                                                                                                                                WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=900 and CTE.SerialNum<>1) THEN prev.DateTime 
                                                                                                  ELSE CTE.DateTime
                                                                                  END
                                                                FROM CTE 
                                                                LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.RowNum = (CTE.RowNum-CTE.SerialNum)+1 AND prev.SkillTargetID=CTE.SkillTargetID 
                                )


                                Z LEFT JOIN RCode R ON R.ReasonCode = Z.ReasonCode  
)
--Select * From CTE2 where [Reason Code]=107 ORDER BY  Activity, [Agent Name] 

Select Activity, Date, Stuff(right(convert(varchar(30), DATEADD(second, -(Sum(Duration)),[Activity]), 109), 14), 9, 4, ' ') AS [Start Time],
[End Time], SkillTargetID, [Agent Name], Event, SUM(Duration) AS [Duration], [Reason Code], Reason From CTE2 
Where [Reason Code]=107
GROUP BY [Activity], Date, [End Time], SkillTargetID, [Agent Name], Event, [Reason Code], Reason
Order By [Agent Name], Activity
```

**Query Logic:**

We are showing Event StartTime and EndTime from TABLEA table by considering Row Number and Serial Number,

```
RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SkillTargetID ORDER BY DateTime, SkillTargetID),
SerialNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SkillTargetID, Event,Duration ORDER BY DateTime),
```

**From TABLEA.**

After fetching the RowNum and SerialNum, we are selecting a field called Activity based on those RowNum and SerialNum values,

```
[Activity] = CASE  WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=1800 and CTE.SerialNum=1) THEN CTE.DateTime
                                                                                                                                WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=900 and CTE.SerialNum=1) THEN CTE.DateTime
                                                                                                                                WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=1800 and CTE.SerialNum<>1) THEN prev.DateTime 
                                                                                                                                WHEN (CTE.Event = 3 AND CTE.Duration=900 and CTE.SerialNum<>1) THEN prev.DateTime 
                                                                                                  ELSE CTE.DateTime
                                                                                  END
                                                                FROM CTE 
                                                                LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.RowNum = (CTE.RowNum-CTE.SerialNum)+1 AND prev.SkillTargetID=CTE.SkillTargetID
```

Start Time and End Time values are based on the above [Activity]. But it is showing incorrect data.

**Reason for this issue:**

If SerialNum is based on SkillTargetID, Event, Duration it is showing different values for same entry and showing 1 for different entries as expected and due to that if we have below scenario we are getting incorrect Start Time and End Time and in the report.

```
Agent Name SkillTargetID Event  Date Time   ReasonText  Duration

Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 10:00    BioBreak    150 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 10:30    BioBreak    1800 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 11:00    BioBreak    1800 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 11:30    BioBreak    1800 Seconds
Sathiya 5000 3  20-08-2018 11:42    BioBreak    720 Seconds
```

SerialNum value will show 1 for First Record as well as last record due to this query is thinking they are different events and not the same but actually all are same continues event that should show as in single row in the report.

Comment: I recommend formatting both the data and SQL so that it's easier to read. Now your data isn't aligned under the headers and parts of the SQL are really hard to read due to indentation. Providing the data in an SQL Fiddle or similar might also help to get answers.

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks for the comment. Let me format and align the question as you said..

Comment: Nobody has answer yet that means your requirement is not clear to anybody.Show. your actual table,expected output and explain logic behind expected output and please ask only one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what I have understood,if output is not ok then care to reexplain the requirement.

Sample data,

```
create table #temp (AgentName varchar(50), SkilltargetID int, Events int,  EventTimes datetime,   ReasonText varchar(50),  Duration int)
insert into #temp values
('Sathiya', 5000, 3,   '2018-08-20 10:00',     'BioBreak',    180 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 10:30',     'BioBreak',   1800 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 11:00',     'BioBreak',    1800 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 11:30',     'BioBreak',    1800 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 11:42',     'BioBreak',    720 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 12:01',     'Lunch',    1140 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 12:30',     'Lunch',    1740 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 12:32',     'Lunch',    120 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 01:00',     'BioBreak',   1680 )
,('Sathiya', 5000, 3,  '2018-08-20 01:29',     'BioBreak',   1740 )
```

Script,

```
;With CTE as
(
select AgentName,SkilltargetID,Events
,ReasonText ,Duration,EventTimes
,ROW_NUMBER()over( order by(select null))rn
from #temp
)
,CTE1 as
(
select AgentName,SkilltargetID,Events
,ReasonText ,Duration,EventTimes
,rn
,1 groupid
from cte
where rn=1

union all

select c.AgentName,c.SkilltargetID,c.Events
,c.ReasonText ,c.Duration,c.EventTimes
,c.rn
,case when c.ReasonText=c1.ReasonText then groupid else groupid+1 end
from cte c
inner join cte1 c1 on c.rn=c1.rn+1


)
,cte3  as
(
select AgentName,SkilltargetID,Events,ReasonText,groupid
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by groupid order by EventTimes desc)rownum  
,EventTimes
from CTE1

)
,cte2  as
(
select groupid,sum(duration) Duration  from CTE1
group by groupid
)

select AgentName,SkilltargetID,Events,ReasonText
,convert(varchar,cast( dateadd(second,-c2.Duration,  c3.EventTimes) as time),100)StartTime
,convert(varchar,cast(c3.EventTimes as time),100) EndTime
,Duration
from cte3 c3
inner join cte2 c2
on c3.groupid=c2.groupid
where c3.rownum=1

drop table #temp
```

Comment: You Genuise.. Your query helped me to fix my issue and this is what I expected. Thanks @KumarHarsh..